# Create a high priority serial dispatch queue with GCD

Tags: objective-c, macos, grand-central-dispatch

How can I create a custom serial queue that runs at high priority?

Right now I'm using `myQueue = dispatch_queue_create("com.MyApp.MyQueue", NULL);` but this doesn't seem to allow for setting a priority?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Create a serial queue, then use `dispatch_set_target_queue()` to set its target queue to the high priority queue.

Here's how:

```
dispatch_set_target_queue(myQueue, dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0));
```

Now `myQueue` should run serially with high priority.
Here's [another SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23112547/how-does-dispatch-set-target-queue-work) if you want to know more.

Comment: ok great, and that still means my queue itself will remain serial but then post its work out to the concurrent queue?

Comment: yup! Should do just what you wanted.

Comment: Wait! Queues can dispatch blocks into other queues?!?

Comment: Sure can. In fact, if I'm remember the code right, serial queues *always* target one of the global concurrent queues in the end. Don't quote me on that one though, been a while since I read that code.

Comment: Awesome! I had no idea that this is even possible (setting a target queue on a queue itself), yet its even in the documentation: `A dispatch queue's priority is inherited from its target queue. Use the dispatch_get_global_queue function to obtain a suitable target queue of the desired priority.`

Comment: This answer is out of date. Better is to use QoS as described in WWDC 2014 video [Power, Performance and Diagnostics: What's new in GCD and XPC](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2014/716/) or as shown in [user2067021's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48616812/1271826).

Answer (score 18):

The [`dispatch_queue_attr_make_with_qos_class`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/1453028-dispatch_queue_attr_make_with_qo) function may be new since the accepted answer was posted, but something like:

```
dispatch_queue_attr_t priorityAttribute = dispatch_queue_attr_make_with_qos_class(
    DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL, QOS_CLASS_USER_INITIATED, -1
);

myQueue = dispatch_queue_create("com.MyApp.MyQueue", priorityAttribute);
```

could give the queue a high priority ('quality of service'). There is a higher QOS class, but `QOS_CLASS_USER_INITIATED` is equivalent to `DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH`.

Comment: This should now be the accepted answer. This is the correct way to do this.

Comment: This is the way to do it. I do a lot of high performance apps. Don't use defaults

Answer (score -3):

is it a requirement that you have a custom queue? If not, you could look at dispatching a block to the high priority global queue, which you can retrieve using:

```
dispatch_queue_t q = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0)
```

keep in mind that this is the global queue so it may impact other concurrent operations.

Comment: The requirement is that I need the queue to be serial.