# How does dispatch_set_target_queue work?

Tags: ios, objective-c, grand-central-dispatch

Due to the lack of material on `dispatch_set_target_queue`, I have come here for help, so thanks!

Here is my test code:

```
dispatch_queue_t mySerialDispatchQueue1 = dispatch_queue_create("come.itenyh", NULL);
dispatch_queue_t mySerialDispatchQueue2 = dispatch_queue_create("come.itenyh1", NULL);

dispatch_set_target_queue(mySerialDispatchQueue1, mySerialDispatchQueue2);

dispatch_async(mySerialDispatchQueue1, ^{[self task:@"s1"];});

dispatch_async(mySerialDispatchQueue2, ^{[self task:@"p1"];});

dispatch_async(mySerialDispatchQueue1, ^{[self task:@"s2"];});

- (void)task:(NSString *)taskid
{

        NSLog(@"Now executing taskid:%@", taskid);

        [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:5];

}
```

Now if I set

```
 dispatch_set_target_queue(mySerialDispatchQueue2, mySerialDispatchQueue1);
```

then the result is:

```
2014-04-16 22:23:49.581 ITGCDLearning[66758:1303] Now executing taskid:s1
2014-04-16 22:23:54.585 ITGCDLearning[66758:1303] Now executing taskid:s2
2014-04-16 22:23:59.586 ITGCDLearning[66758:1303] Now executing taskid:p1
```

and on the contrary, If I set

```
dispatch_set_target_queue(mySerialDispatchQueue1, mySerialDispatchQueue2);
```

then the result is:

```
2014-04-16 22:28:37.910 ITGCDLearning[66795:1303] Now executing taskid:s1
2014-04-16 22:28:42.913 ITGCDLearning[66795:1303] Now executing taskid:p1
2014-04-16 22:28:47.915 ITGCDLearning[66795:1303] Now executing taskid:s2
```

I know that the `dispatch_set_target_queue` function can

- change the priorty of the queue
- create a hierarchy of dispatch queues.

I think it is the second point that leads to the result in my code, but don't really know the specific details. Can someone explain it to me?

Answer (score 3):

According to me when you set a target queue to other you are synchronizing the task of both the queue so
**In first case**:

```
dispatch_set_target_queue(mySerialDispatchQueue2, mySerialDispatchQueue1);
```

`mySerialDispatchQueue1` is target queue so all the task added in `mySerialDispatchQueue2` is also enqueued from the `mySerialDispatchQueue1`. As it is target queue.So `mySerialDispatchQueue1` has already two task so other one from queue `mySerialDispatchQueue2` is added later.

**In second Case:**

```
dispatch_set_target_queue(mySerialDispatchQueue1, mySerialDispatchQueue2);
```

your target queue is `mySerialDispatchQueue2` so in start when there is no task then task from `mySerialDispatchQueue1` is added in the `mySerialDispatchQueue2` then its own task is in queue. So in this way task has been added.