# How to protect my working thread from being preempted by system processes?

Tags: ios, multithreading

I'm working on some AR Game which contains three major modules:

- an AVCaptureSession to capture video frame data
- an Algorithm module
- a Render Engine

The routine of app is very simple:

- obtain one frame of data from AVCaptureVideoDataOutput, then pass it to algorithm module
- algorithm module processes frame data on its own dispatch queue, then pass the results to render engine
- render engine uses the results to update whole virutal scene

Each module has its own working thread (or dispatch queue), but only one module is active because they work serially.

The problem is when the app run on some low level devices (like iPhone6), the fps is not stable. After profiling, I found that sometimes, both cpu cores are occupied by some system process (like medieserverd, backboardd ...) and my working threads could be preempted for a long time (like 10ms or even longer)

Is there any way to make sure my working thread can occupy at least one cpu core?

Now I'm using dispatch queues to organize my work tasks. Will it be better to use NSThread directly?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way to make sure my working thread can occupy at least one cpu core?

Generally not, the kernel may always decide to preempt your thread. But you can indicate the importance of your thread, to reduce the chance of that happening.

> I'm using dispatch queues to organize my work tasks.

Try increasing the priority of your queue, e.g. like this:

`dispatch_set_target_queue(myQueue, dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0));`

More details on setting queue priority [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23112547/how-does-dispatch-set-target-queue-work).

> Will it be better to use NSThread directly?

NSThread has more way to adjust priority, so yes that might give better results.

If you switch to `NSThread`, you will be able to set its [`qualityOfService`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsthread/1409426-qualityofservice) and [`threadPriority`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsthread/1407523-setthreadpriority).

That should be sufficient to give your thread more CPU time. If not, you can try the lower-level API's to directly adjust [Mach thread scheduling](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Darwin/Conceptual/KernelProgramming/scheduler/scheduler.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000905-CH211-BABHGEFA).