# Serialized priority queues in GCD

Tags: multithreading, grand-central-dispatch, priority-queue

I have an existing piece of code from the API dark ages.  It's a thread based on MPCreateTask.  It looks like I can move it to GCG queues, but there is a little complication. There are currently three queues based off of MPCreateQueue that are used for three priorities.

In GCD I have figured out, and tested the following code as proof of concept for a GCD refactoring ( gosh I hate that word, but it fits ).

First, Is this going to do what I expect namely, all actions ( blocks input to the routines ) will be serial.  Actions will have the priorities specified by the routine dispatching them.

Second, Is there a better way to do this?

```
// set up three serial queues
dispatch_queue_t queueA = dispatch_queue_create("app.queue.A" , DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL);
dispatch_queue_t queueB = dispatch_queue_create("app.queue.B" , DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL);
dispatch_queue_t queueC = dispatch_queue_create("app.queue.C" , DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL);

// set the target queues so that all blocks posted to any of the queues are serial
// ( the priority of the queues will be set by queueC.
dispatch_set_target_queue( queueB, queueC ) ;
dispatch_set_target_queue( queueA, queueB ) ;

void lowPriorityDispatch( dispatch_block_t lowAction )
{
     dispatch_async( queueC, ^{
        lowAction() ;
     }) ;
}
void mediumPriorityDispatch( dispatch_block_t mediumAction )
{
     dispatch_async( queueB, ^{
        dispatch_suspend( queueC) ;
        mediumAction() ;
        dispatch_resume( queueC ) ;
     }) ;
}
void highPriorityDispatch( dispatch_block_t highAction )
{
     dispatch_async( queueA, ^{
        dispatch_suspend( queueC) ;
        dispatch_suspend( queueB) ;
        highAction() ;
        dispatch_resume( queueB ) ;
        dispatch_resume( queueC ) ;
     }) ;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

I'm not sure if anyone has provided you the answer yet but don't do this. At best, you will just set up priorities for just the three queues here. At worst, you are not doing anything. GCD has facilities for creating priorities for each queue. See dispatch_queue_attr_make_with_qos_class [dispatch_queue_attr_make_with_qos_class](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/dispatch_queue_attr_make_with_qos_class).

A better solution would be:

```
dispatch_queue_attr_t highPriorityAttr = dispatch_queue_attr_make_with_qos_class (DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL, QOS_CLASS_USER_INITIATED,-1);
dispatch_queue_t queueA = dispatch_queue_create ("app.queue.A",highPriorityAttr);

dispatch_queue_attr_t mediumPriorityAttr = dispatch_queue_attr_make_with_qos_class (DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL, QOS_CLASS_UTILITY,-1);
dispatch_queue_t queueB = dispatch_queue_create ("app.queue.B",mediumPriorityAttr);

dispatch_queue_attr_t lowPriorityAttr = dispatch_queue_attr_make_with_qos_class (DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL, QOS_CLASS_BACKGROUND,-1);
dispatch_queue_t queueC = dispatch_queue_create ("app.queue.C",lowPriorityAttr);
```

Then use each like:

```
dispatch_async(queueA,highAction);
dispatch_async(queueB,mediumAction);
dispatch_async(queueC,lowAction);
```

Comment: Note that dispatch_queue_attr_make_with_qos_class and the ability to specify queue priority for dispatch_queue_create was introduced in iOS8. For earlier iOS versions, use dispatch_set_target_queue() as described here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17690878/962153