# Set priority for custom created serial asynchronous queue

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, grand-central-dispatch, thread-priority

How can I set high priority to a custom created serial asynchronous queue using GCD's?

I had a look at [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17690740/create-a-high-priority-serial-dispatch-queue-with-gcd) where suggestion is made to make use of `dispatch_set_target_queue()` & Pass High Priority Queue (`DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH`) which is a Concurrent Queue to custom serial asynchronous queue.

My understanding is that this will make all the tasks on the Serial Queue execute concurrently. Is my understanding correct? If so, what is an alternate solution?

Comment: Why the heck would somebody down vote this without comment? I count three upvotes on the answers (as of 13th of May 2015), that means the question helped at least three people find something they valued. People seem mean on this site sometimes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your queue will still be serial. It will just be performing its tasks, one at a time, in one slot of the high priority, global, concurrent background queue.  Once created, a serial queue cannot be "made concurrent" by any means.

Similarly, if you create a concurrent queue and you set it to target a serial queue, it effectively becomes serial.

This is all covered in this [man page](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/dispatch_set_target_queue.3.html).

Comment: Can you add some reference link to Apple documentation which says this..Coz I didn't find any. Also is there a way of setting priority of queue only NEXT to main_queue().

Comment: Link added. What do you mean by, "Also is there a way of setting priority of queue only NEXT to main_queue()?" If you mean "is there a way of setting queue priority such that the main thread always has the highest priority?" my belief, without proof, would be that you can't explicitly do that, but that, in practice, any target priority lower than `DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH` would effectively meet that requirement.

Comment: I know that the TOP Most Priority queue is the mainQueue(). The custom queue that I created shall have the Next Highest Priority. Does that sound clear?

Comment: Well, to be honest, you don't have any control over what priority the main queue has. If you believe that the main queue always has top priority, then the way to make a queue have the next highest priority would be to target it to the global concurrent queue with `DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH`.

Answer (score 6):

Prior to iOS 8 setting the target queue to a high priority queue is how you would achieve this. Your queue will remain serial even though the target queue is concurrent.

As of version 8.0 there is another way to do this:

```
dispatch_queue_attr_t queueAttrs = dispatch_queue_attr_make_with_qos_class(
    DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL,
    QOS_CLASS_USER_INITIATED /* Same as DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH */, 
    0
);

dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_queue_create("myqueue",queueAttrs);
```

Comment: The documentation for the `relative_priority` parameter states: "A negative offset from the maximum supported scheduler priority for the given quality-of-service class. This value must be less than `0` and greater than `MIN_QOS_CLASS_PRIORITY`". But you are passing `0` here.